# js цикл выводит только первый результат

Tags: javascript, node.js

При получении информации с rest.db.ripe.net цикл выводит только последний результат

```
{"service" : {
  "name" : "search"
},
"parameters" : {
  "inverse-lookup" : { },
  "type-filters" : { },
  "flags" : { },
  "query-strings" : {
    "query-string" : [ {
      "value" : "46.180.122.12"
    } ]
  },
  "sources" : { }
},
"objects" : {
  "object" : [ {
    "type" : "inetnum",
    "link" : {
      "type" : "locator",
      "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/inetnum/46.180.0.0 - 46.180.255.255"
    },
    "source" : {
      "id" : "ripe"
    },
    "primary-key" : {
      "attribute" : [ {
        "name" : "inetnum",
        "value" : "46.180.0.0 - 46.180.255.255"
      } ]
    },
    "attributes" : {
      "attribute" : [ {
        "name" : "inetnum",
        "value" : "46.180.0.0 - 46.180.255.255"
      }, {
        "name" : "netname",
        "value" : "GOODLINE-INFO"
      }, {
        "name" : "descr",
        "value" : "E-Light-Telecom"
      }, {
        "name" : "descr",
        "value" : "Russia, Kemerovo, Kuznecky 18"
      }, {
        "name" : "country",
        "value" : "RU"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/person/KK7315-RIPE"
        },
        "name" : "admin-c",
        "value" : "KK7315-RIPE",
        "referenced-type" : "person"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/person/AK22501-RIPE"
        },
        "name" : "tech-c",
        "value" : "AK22501-RIPE",
        "referenced-type" : "person"
      }, {
        "name" : "status",
        "value" : "ASSIGNED PA"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/mntner/ELT-MNT"
        },
        "name" : "mnt-by",
        "value" : "ELT-MNT",
        "referenced-type" : "mntner"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/mntner/ELT-MNT"
        },
        "name" : "mnt-lower",
        "value" : "ELT-MNT",
        "referenced-type" : "mntner"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/mntner/ELT-MNT"
        },
        "name" : "mnt-domains",
        "value" : "ELT-MNT",
        "referenced-type" : "mntner"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/mntner/ELT-MNT"
        },
        "name" : "mnt-routes",
        "value" : "ELT-MNT",
        "referenced-type" : "mntner"
      }, {
        "name" : "created",
        "value" : "2011-06-22T08:11:59Z"
      }, {
        "name" : "last-modified",
        "value" : "2023-04-28T08:09:45Z"
      }, {
        "name" : "source",
        "value" : "RIPE"
      } ]
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "person",
    "link" : {
      "type" : "locator",
      "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/person/AK22501-RIPE"
    },
    "source" : {
      "id" : "ripe"
    },
    "primary-key" : {
      "attribute" : [ {
        "name" : "nic-hdl",
        "value" : "AK22501-RIPE"
      } ]
    },
    "attributes" : {
      "attribute" : [ {
        "name" : "person",
        "value" : "Aleksej Korol'kov"
      }, {
        "name" : "address",
        "value" : "Russian Federation"
      }, {
        "name" : "address",
        "value" : "Kemerovo"
      }, {
        "name" : "address",
        "value" : "650099 Kuznetsky 18"
      }, {
        "name" : "phone",
        "value" : "+73842452999"
      }, {
        "name" : "phone",
        "value" : "+73842452893"
      }, {
        "name" : "nic-hdl",
        "value" : "AK22501-RIPE"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/mntner/ELT-MNT"
        },
        "name" : "mnt-by",
        "value" : "ELT-MNT",
        "referenced-type" : "mntner"
      }, {
        "name" : "created",
        "value" : "2023-03-10T07:32:26Z"
      }, {
        "name" : "last-modified",
        "value" : "2023-03-10T07:32:26Z"
      }, {
        "name" : "source",
        "value" : "RIPE",
        "comment" : "Filtered"
      } ]
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "person",
    "link" : {
      "type" : "locator",
      "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/person/KK7315-RIPE"
    },
    "source" : {
      "id" : "ripe"
    },
    "primary-key" : {
      "attribute" : [ {
        "name" : "nic-hdl",
        "value" : "KK7315-RIPE"
      } ]
    },
    "attributes" : {
      "attribute" : [ {
        "name" : "person",
        "value" : "Konstantin Karavaev"
      }, {
        "name" : "address",
        "value" : "Russian Federation"
      }, {
        "name" : "address",
        "value" : "Kemerovo"
      }, {
        "name" : "address",
        "value" : "650099 Kuznetsky 18"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/organisation/ORG-EA385-RIPE"
        },
        "name" : "org",
        "value" : "ORG-EA385-RIPE",
        "referenced-type" : "organisation"
      }, {
        "name" : "phone",
        "value" : "+73842452999"
      }, {
        "name" : "phone",
        "value" : "+73842452893"
      }, {
        "name" : "nic-hdl",
        "value" : "KK7315-RIPE"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/mntner/ELT-MNT"
        },
        "name" : "mnt-by",
        "value" : "ELT-MNT",
        "referenced-type" : "mntner"
      }, {
        "name" : "created",
        "value" : "2018-11-14T03:45:11Z"
      }, {
        "name" : "last-modified",
        "value" : "2018-11-14T03:53:45Z"
      }, {
        "name" : "source",
        "value" : "RIPE",
        "comment" : "Filtered"
      } ]
    }
  }, {
    "type" : "route",
    "link" : {
      "type" : "locator",
      "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/route/46.180.96.0/19AS39927"
    },
    "source" : {
      "id" : "ripe"
    },
    "primary-key" : {
      "attribute" : [ {
        "name" : "route",
        "value" : "46.180.96.0/19"
      }, {
        "name" : "origin",
        "value" : "AS39927"
      } ]
    },
    "attributes" : {
      "attribute" : [ {
        "name" : "route",
        "value" : "46.180.96.0/19"
      }, {
        "name" : "descr",
        "value" : "Goodline.info"
      }, {
        "name" : "origin",
        "value" : "AS39927"
      }, {
        "link" : {
          "type" : "locator",
          "href" : "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/mntner/ELT-MNT"
        },
        "name" : "mnt-by",
        "value" : "ELT-MNT",
        "referenced-type" : "mntner"
      }, {
        "name" : "created",
        "value" : "2010-12-22T11:28:32Z"
      }, {
        "name" : "last-modified",
        "value" : "2010-12-22T11:28:32Z"
      }, {
        "name" : "source",
        "value" : "RIPE"
      } ]
    }
  } ]
},
"terms-and-conditions" : {
  "type" : "locator",
  "href" : "https://apps.db.ripe.net/docs/HTML-Terms-And-Conditions"
},
"version" : {
  "version" : "1.109.1",
  "timestamp" : "2023-12-06T15:18:06Z",
  "commit-id" : "acc20f7"
}
}
```

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
fetch('http://rest.db.ripe.net/search.json?query-string=46.180.122.12')
.then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    function getData() {
      let content = [];
      let i = 0;
      let j = 0;
      let json = res;
      let h = []     
      for (i = 0; i < json['objects']['object'].length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < json['objects']['object'][i]['attributes']['attribute'].length; j++) {
            //console.log(json['objects']['object'][i]['attributes']['attribute'][j]['name'])
          switch (json['objects']['object'][i]['attributes']['attribute'][j]['name']) {
            case 'country':
              {
                content['country'] = json['objects']['object'][i]['attributes']['attribute'][j]['value'];
              };
              break;
            case 'address':
              {
                content['address'] = json['objects']['object'][i]['attributes']['attribute'][j]['value'];   

              };
              break;
            case 'phone':
              {
                content['phone'] = json['objects']['object'][i]['attributes']['attribute'][j]['value'];
              };
              break;
            case 'person':
              {
                content['person'] = json['objects']['object'][i]['attributes']['attribute'][j]['value'];
              };
              break;
          }
        }
      }
      return content;
    }
    let getI = getData()
    console.log(getI)
  });
```

Результат: [
country: 'RU',
person: 'Konstantin Karavaev',
address: '650099 Kuznetsky 18',
phone: '+73842452893'
]

Согласно WHOIS:
address:        Russian Federation
address:        Kemerovo
address:        650099 Kuznetsky 18

Аналогичная ситуация и с кейсом phone... каким образом получать все поля address, чтобы результат был к примеру: Russian Federation, Kemerovo, 650099 Kuznetsky 18. Полей с address может быть как 1 так и 10..

Comment: Если добавите в вопрос объект, который получает fetch, то возможно будет больше идей по реализации

Comment: а почему он должен выводить не последний вариант?

Comment: яваскрипт - это не пхп, поэтому добавляя в массив свойства в виде `content['country']` можно получать неожиданные результаты

Comment: Добавил объект, который получает fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути Все что Вам нужно - сделать элементы `phone` и `address` массива `content` - массивами и каждое найденное соответствие добавлять в эти массивы.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
fetch('http://rest.db.ripe.net/search.json?query-string=46.180.122.12')
.then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    function getData() {
      let content = [];
      let i = 0;
      let j = 0;
      let json = res;
      let h = []     
      //приведем код в более читабельный вид - заведем доп. переменные, 
      //чтобы глаз не рябило от длинных строк с под-элементами
      let object = json['objects']['object'];
      for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {

        let attr = object[i]['attributes']['attribute'];  
        //создадим объект в котором будем хранить всю инфу 
        //так как адресов может быть несколько - укажем, 
        //что поле `address` объекта само является массивом
        //тоже самое делаем с телефонами и любыми другими полями 
        //значений которых может быть не одно
        let user = {'country': '', 'address':[], 'phone': [], 'persion': ''}
        for (j = 0; j < attr.length; j++) {
          //console.log(attr[j]['name'])
          switch (attr[j]['name']) {
            case 'country':
              {
               user.country = attr[j]['value'];
              };
              break;
            case 'address':
              {
                //добавляем в массив адресов каждый наденный адрес
                user.address.push( attr[j]['value'] );   

              };
              break;
            case 'phone':
              {
                //добавляем в массив телефонов каждый наденный телефон
                user.phone.push( attr[j]['value'] );
              };
              break;
            case 'person':
              {
                user.person = attr[j]['value'];
              };
              break;
          }
        }
        //Добавляем объект с полученной информацией в выходной массив
        content.push( user );
      }
      return content;
    }
    let getI = getData()
    console.log(getI)
  });
```

Comment: Я примерно такой вариант уже пробовал.. на выходе получаю                                                                                               let content['address'] = [];
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['

Comment: Поправил код. Запутался в языках :) Слишком много их знаю и периодически путаю синтаксис :) В `JS` нет ассоциативных массивов как `PHP` и конструкция `ar['keyword'] = value` некорректна. Там все через `push` и проще всего сделать массив объектов.

Comment: И как всегда - вместо того, чтобы написать что в коде не так - ну или дать свой ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ответ - лепят минус. Детский сад...

Comment: _конструкция `ar['keyword'] = value` некорректна._ - эта конструкция корректна, просто свойство добавится не так как ожидается.

Comment: Спасибо большое!! На выходе вот что получаю: [
  { country: 'RU', address: [], phone: [], person: [] },
  {
    country: '',
    address: [ 'Russian Federation', 'Kemerovo', '650099 Kuznetsky 18' ],
    phone: [ '+73842452999', '+73842452893' ],
    person: [ "Aleksej Korol'kov" ]
  },
  {
    country: '',
    address: [ 'Russian Federation', 'Kemerovo', '650099 Kuznetsky 18' ],
    phone: [ '+73842452999', '+73842452893' ],
    person: [ 'Konstantin Karavaev' ]
  },
  { country: '', address: [], phone: [], person: [] }
]
В вопросе я добавил объект, который получает fetch

Comment: Проблема с `country` из-за того, что данное поле сидит в `objects.object[0].attributes`, а `address` и `phone` в `objects.object[1].attributes`, если мы считаем, что вся информация, что мы получили по одной интересующей нас  персоне, то тогда `let user = ...` перенести на место `let content = [];`, строчку `content.push( user );` убрать, ну и `return content;` заменить на `return user;`

Comment: @Grundy ну если она работает не так как ожидается, то получается что она `некорректна в данном месте` :)

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин Спасибо большое!

Comment: Как говорится - `не во что` :)

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин, некорректна - это когда ошибка, в данном случае все работает.

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин еще момент, бывает что в поле address закидывает одинаковые адреса (потому что и в объекте [0] и [1] есть одинаковые адреса) как исключить повторный вывод ?

Comment: Логично предположить, что проверять этот массив на то, что в нем нет такого значения. Можете сами в цикле перебрать и сравнить, можете подключить `jQuery` и через `$.InArray`, возможно и в `pureJS` что-то на этот счет встроенное есть...

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин вот такое решение вроде бы.. 
let getADD = getI.address.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
})